Lines outlining a semicircle
I am trying to draw the following

Starting with draw a) (and with a lot of effort), here is what I have for the moment
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % Outer circle
    \draw [thick] (0,0) circle (3cm);
    
    % Horizontal line
    \draw[gray] (-3,0)--(3,0);
    
    % Left-hand side arcs
    
    \draw[gray] (-3,0.25) arc[start angle=70,end angle=-65, radius=0.3cm];
    
    \draw[gray] (-2.83,1) arc[start angle=70,end angle=-65, radius=1.2cm];
    
    \draw[gray] (-2.3,1.9) arc[start angle=50, end angle=-50, radius=2.5cm];
    
    \draw[gray] (-1.2,2.73) arc[start angle=40, end angle=-40, radius=4.25cm];
    
    % Right-hand side arcs
    
    \draw[gray] (3,0.25) arc[start angle=110,end angle=245, radius=0.3cm];
    
    \draw[gray] (2.83,1) arc[start angle=110,end angle=245, radius=1.2cm];
    
    \draw[gray] (2.3,1.9) arc[start angle=130, end angle=230, radius=2.5cm];
    
    \draw[gray] (1.2,2.73) arc[start angle=140, end angle=220, radius=4.25cm];
    
    % Straight line crossing the poles
    
    \draw[gray] (0,3) -- (0,-3);
    
    % Ellipses
    
    \draw [gray] (0,0) ellipse (3cm and 1cm);
    \draw [gray] (0,0) ellipse (3cm and 2cm);
    \draw [gray] (0,0) ellipse (3cm and 2.8cm);
    
    %====== Red sector
    
    %Upper semicircle
    \draw[red,thick] (3,0) arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=3cm];
    
    \draw[thick,red] (0.6,-2.95) arc[start angle=0.5, end angle=180,radius=0.6cm];
\end{tikzpicture}

It produce the following image

I have two issues: First, I drew a semicircle, whereas in diagram a), it appears more like a bean or half an egg, perhaps. Secondly, I don't know how to draw the red lines on the left and right sides of this 'egg' that extend in part of the south pole.
Regarding image b), it seems more difficult than a), but one step at the time.

Obvious it is some sort of plot. Why do you not use the correct formula instead of drawing random lines? For me it looks like a grid on a transverse cylindrical projection, -but you must know what it is! -as you wish to reproduce it.

I can draw the Wulff net, but I do not know the equation of the red lines. As hpekristiansen said, you should find a formula for those lines. By the way, those are probably not supposed to be ellipses, but instead arcs of individual circles.

I see. Thank you for the feedback. Regarding the plot of the red lines, if I would know them, I would definitely had plot them as an equation.

Could be part of a bipolar coordinates system?

Unless you want to reproduce the graphs for a cartoon or similar!?, you must know something about them. Maybe you do not have a formula, but surely you know what the are suppose to show - then we could help.

@hpekristiansen, "Maybe you do not have a formula, but surely you know what the are suppose to show", it correspond to (part of) the geometry of a particular gravitational solution. I am trying to draw a picture on how the solution behaves at certain limits, e.g., when $r\to\infty$, $r\to 0$, $y\to\pm \infty$, or when $y$ goes to a particular value, where $0\leq r<\infty$ and $-\infty<y<\infty$.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[thick] (0,0) circle[radius=3];

\foreach \tickAngle/\tickLabel in {-120/a,-90/b,-60/c}{
\draw[red, very thick] (\tickAngle:2.9) -- (\tickAngle:3.1);
\node at (\tickAngle:3.3) {\tickLabel};
}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\eggAngle}{12}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\eggLooseness}{2.2}
\draw[red, thick] (-90-\eggAngle:3) to[out=90-\eggAngle, in=90+\eggAngle, looseness=\eggLooseness] (-90+\eggAngle:3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


